How to click on a dynamically loaded dropdown menu using Selenium?
Good afternoon, everyone.
I am trying to perform web scraping on the following website: https://www.universal-assistance.com/ar-es/home.html, and I am facing a challenge.
The site is dynamic, and I can't get my script to click on the area where the destination is selected (e.g., Europe). I am also having the same issue with the date fields, as I am unable to make the script click on or fill in those fields. Since there is no clear element acting as a button, I am struggling to make the automation work properly.
I would appreciate it if anyone could lend me a hand to find a way to complete this form and then extract the data from the following page with the prices.
Thank you very much in advance for any help or suggestions you can provide.
I have tried creating a script using Selenium directly.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Browser configuration
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

# Open the page
driver.get('https://www.universal-assistance.com/ar-es/home.html')

# Try to click on the destination field
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    destination_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'item-opener')))
    destination_field.click()
except Exception as e:
    print("Error:", e)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()

